# Gerar número aleatório ao ativar planilha no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou aqui pois acredito que só com ajuda do VBA vou conseguir o que pretendo fazer, que é o seguinte:

Estou a desenvolver um pequeno jogo no Excel e tenho que usar números aleatórios, acontece que sempre que carrego, removo ou escrevo algo, os valores alteram-se. Procuro uma maneira onde os números aleatórios só sejam gerados quando entro na folha (planilha) pretendida.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Adicione à pergunta algum código que você já fez.

Comment: esse é o problema Vba nunca tive aulas e fui vendo pelo google e a unica coisa que me surgiu foi a do screen refresh mas mesmo assim continua sem funcionar

Comment: Coloca o VBA que você tem aí para vermos o que é.

Comment: Eu tenho produtos e quero valores aleatorios para eles o problema é que eles mudam sempre que carrego em algo...

nao consigo colocar o codigo completo e mesmo assim acho que é impossivel o que quero fazer com isto dos numeros aleatorios...

Comment: E ele está maioritariamente feito com coisas basicas de excel e uso o vba para fazer o que não dá no excel

Answer (score 4):

Cada planilha de um arquivo Excel possui um evento chamado `Activate`, que é executado quando a planilha é ativada, você pode utilizar esse evento e gerar os números aleatórios nele.

Abra seu arquivo Excel e entre no `VBA` através da combinação de teclas `ALT + F11`, procure no `Project Explorer`, que normalmente fica no canto superior esquerdo, a planilha que você deseja criar a macro e dê um clique duplo nela.

[image: VBA - Project Explorer]

Será exibida uma janela onde você pode digitar seus códigos, nessa janela existem dois combos, um que representa o objeto (que normalmente vem escrito `(Geral)`) e o outro que representa o evento (que normalmente vem escrito `(Declaração)`). Para selecionar o evento, você precisa selecionar o objeto primeiro, então no objeto selecione `Worksheet` (quando você fizer isso, será adicionado no seu código um evento automaticamente, você pode removê-lo) e no evento selecione `Activate`, nesse momento você irá ver algo assim:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

End Sub
```

Supondo que você quer exibir o número aleatório na célula `A1`, então você pode fazer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Randomize
    ' o número 6 representa o valor máximo e o 1 o valor mínimo,
    ' esses números podem ser alterados conforme sua necessidade
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))
End Sub
```

Dessa maneira, toda vez que você ativar a `Plan1` será executado o código acima, gerando um número aleatório e colocando ele na célula `A1`.

> **Dica**: caso você queira fazer uma macro, mas não tenha ideia de como codificar e quais propriedades usar, você pode usar a funcionalidade oferecida pelo Excel e iniciar a gravação de uma macro, ai você faz manualmente o que você quer na planilha e depois finaliza a gravação, feito isso será gerado um módulo (no `VBA`) que contém todo o código referente ao que você fez manualmente.

Seguem algumas informações sobre o código utilizado:
`Randomize` - inicializa o gerador de números aleatórios.
`ActiveSheet` - representa a planilha ativa.
`Range` - representa uma célula, uma linha, uma coluna ou um intervalo.
`CInt` - converte uma expressão para um inteiro.
`Int` - retorna a parte inteira de um número.
`Rnd` - gera um número aleatório menor que 1 e maior ou igual a 0, se o `Randomize` não for utilizado, toda vez que a planilha é aberta a mesma sequência de números é gerada, conforme é informado [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8zedbtdt(v=vs.90).aspx).

> **Nota**: como você está trabalhando com Macros, você terá que salvar seu arquivo Excel como `Pasta de Trabalho Habilitada para Macro Excel`.